Avoid 'Number Stored as Text' Warning in Excel Using Apache POI While Writing Numeric Strings
I am working on a Java project where I need to generate an Excel file using Apache POI. One of the columns in the Excel file contains account numbers, which are numeric but need to be stored as text (string) in the Excel sheet. However, when the file is opened in Excel, it shows a warning: "Number stored as text" for those cells.
What I Have Tried:
1.I used the DataFormat class in Apache POI to set the cell format to text (@).
2.I also attempted various workarounds like prefixing the values with a single quote ('), but this makes the single quote visible in Excel, which I do not want.
3.I tried setting the cell style explicitly to text and confirmed the values are written as strings, but the warning persists.
Expected Outcome:
1.The account numbers should remain as strings (not actual numbers) in the Excel file.
2.Excel should not display any warnings such as "Number stored as text" when the file is opened.
code :
public class ExcelWriter {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     // Define the file name
     String fileName = "EmployeeDetails.xlsx";

     // Create a Workbook
     Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

     // Create a Sheet
     Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Employee Data");

     // Define header titles
     String[] headers = {"Serial Number", "Employee Name", "Account Number", "Number"};

     // Create header row
     Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
     CellStyle headerStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
     // ...existing code...

     // Create a CellStyle for text format
     CellStyle textStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
     DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
     textStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("@"));

     // Sample data
     Object[][] data = {
         {1, "John Doe", "123456789", 1000},
         {2, "Jane Smith", "987654321", 2000}
     };

     // Fill data
     int rowNum = 1;
     for (Object[] rowData : data) {
         Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
         for (int colNum = 0; colNum < rowData.length; colNum++) {
             Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum);
             if (colNum == 2) { // Account Number column
                 cell.setCellStyle(textStyle);
                 cell.setCellValue(rowData[colNum].toString());
             } else {
                 if (rowData[colNum] instanceof String) {
                     cell.setCellValue((String) rowData[colNum]);
                 } else if (rowData[colNum] instanceof Integer) {
                     cell.setCellValue((Integer) rowData[colNum]);
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     // Write the output to a file
     try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName)) {
         workbook.write(fileOut);
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
}


I'm pretty sure that's excel trying to be 'helpful'. It's not a property of the cell and therefore not something you can fix, with any tool.

Ok I got but I want this solution if you know let me know

I tell you: "There is no solution". You.. clearly do not understand what I'm telling you, or refuse to accept it.

Ok thank you even though I tried a lot but I am not able to resolve I also think as you told
